# Two stream processing depending on clause filtering java 8

Tags: dictionary, lambda, java-8, flatmap

I have Set firstSet and Set secondSet.
I need to get final Set beans;

```
Set<Bean> beans = new HashSet<Bean>();
        for(BigDecimal element: firstSet){
            if(secondSet.contains(element)){
                beans.add(new BeanBuilder().id(element).isNew(Boolean.TRUE).build());
            } else {
                beans.add(new BeanBuilder().id(element).isNew(Boolean.FALSE).build());
            }
        }
```

How can I write it using lambda-expression? (need to parse two stream).

```
Set<BEBean> arr = firstSet
        .stream()
                   .flatMap( if(secondSet::contains) {
                new BeanBuilder().id(x).isNew(Boolean.TRUE).build();
                } else {
                new BEBuilder().id(x).name(Boolean.FALSE).build();
                })
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: I just need to parse two stream depending on clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just avoid the code duplication altogether:

```
Set<BEBean> beans = availableResources
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new BeanBuilder().id(e).isNew(secondSet.contains(e)).build())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Note that you could have avoided the code duplication in the loop as well:

```
Set<Bean> beans = new HashSet<Bean>();
for(BigDecimal element: firstSet)
    beans.add(new BeanBuilder().id(element).isNew(secondSet.contains(element)).build());
```